# Read files from directory to create a ZIP hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, zip

I'm looking for Hadoop examples, something more complex than the wordcount example.

What I want to do It's read the files in a directory in Hadoop and get a zip, so I have thought to collect al the files in the map class and create the zip file in the reduce class.

Can anyone give me a link to a tutorial or example than can help me to built it?

**I don't want anyone to do this for me, I'm asking for a link with better examples than the wordaccount.**

**I almost get it, if you need it: https://github.com/flopezluis/testing-hadoop**

Comment: you need to try and we will be happy to help

Comment: :) that's what i'm doing, thank you for being so nice.  I'm doing a class like this MapClass extends MapReduceBase implements

   Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, CompressedWritable>. The idea come from because my files have text, that's why the second parameter is Text, and the last one is CompressedWritable. Again I really appreciate your disposition. Stackoverflow is what it is  because of this.

Comment: How many files / zips do you have to create? I'm not sure this is a well suited problem for map reduce seeing as all the files need to go to one machine to build the zip. Now if you have 1000's of directories, and you needed to zip each one up into it's own zip file, that would be more suitable.

Comment: that's it. I have several directories and each directory has a lot of files. I want to zip each directory in its own zip. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to to normalize the structured data in records, coming in from several inputs and then process it. Based on it, i think you really need to look at [this article](http://blog.data-miners.com/2010/01/hadoop-and-mapreduce-normalizing-data.html) which helped me in past. It included How To Normalize Data Using Hadoop/MapReduce and provide Java based source code as below:

- Step 1: Extract the column value pairs from the original data.
- Step 2: Extract column-value Pairs Not In Master ID File
- Step 3: Calculate the Maximum ID for Each Column in the Master File
- Step 4: Calculate a New ID for the Unmatched Values
- Step 5: Merge the New Ids with the Existing Master IDs
- Step 6: Replace the Values in the Original Data with IDs

There is another examples about **Method for Reading and Writing General Record Structures** using new Writable and InputFormat classes in JAVA. Have a look [here](http://www.data-miners.com/blog/2009/12/hadoop-and-mapreduce-method-for-reading.html).